# How to display Zip Code or Postal Code using MapBox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios, mapbox-ios-maps

My goal is to display Zip Codes or Postal Codes using Mapbox's iOS SDK for USA only postal codes;

I am currently able to display the boundaries for Zip Codes and the international postal/zip code, for example "USP227518" when I actually want to display "27518"

I've tried using `mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures()` and was able to successfully display a modified string value as desired, however this doesn't solve my problem because I need to display the long zipcode with the prefix 'USP2' in order for it to find the Feature and display a map annotation without the prefix. This causes a visual overlap

I also tried 'mapboxMap.querySourceFeatures()' and was unable to retrieve any data at all from any of my sources

Here is the code I use to display the zip codes as given by MapBox

```
try mapboxMapView.mapboxMap.style.updateLayer(withId: MapConstants.symbolLayerIdentifier, type: SymbolLayer.self) { layer in

    layer.textField = .expression(Expression(.number) {
        Exp(.get) { "id" }
        zipCodes // Array of strings all with 'USP2' prefix
        Exp(.get) { "id" } 
        ""                  
    })
}
```

Is there some way to drop the prefixes or to query the source features for zip code points from the source `points_postal_2`?

I also have no idea where `Exp(.get) { "id" }` comes from. My best guess is it comes from here https://docs.mapbox.com/data/boundaries/reference/feature-lookup-tables/ . `unit_code` from that doc didn't work for me in place of "id" even when I removed the 'USP2' prefix from the zipCodes string array values

How do I display the zip codes on a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undocumented MapBox iOS SDK is a tricky library.

Slice is what I needed, and how does one use it, great question, it's not documented nor do any examples seem to exist!

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.14.0/Structs/Expression/Operator.html#/s:10MapboxMaps10ExpressionV8OperatorO5sliceyA2EmF

```
 try mapView.mapboxMap.style.updateLayer(withId: MyMapLayerName, type: SymbolLayer.self) { layer in
     layer.textField = .expression(Expression(.match) {
          Exp(.get) { "id" }
          myZipCodeStringArray
          Exp(.slice) { // Drop first 4 characters, the prefix
               Exp(.get) { "id" }
               4
          }
          "" //not available
     })
```